# AjaxFileupload multiple asynchronous file upload

Tags: c#, ajax, file-upload

I need to find a way to upload asynchronously multiple files.

I want to make a smtp client, User can chose files, create message and then send the mail.

I use ajaxfileupload but it create a folder witch look like c:/windows/tem/_ajaxFileUpload/[a guid]/[uploaded files]

is it possible to determine the guid and then find files to attach without saving it to an other folder.

this must be done after user click on send button.

Answer (score 0):

One possible option is the HTML 5 File Api which allows client side uploads. Here is a tutorial on it http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

I have used it in conjunction with a MVC 4 C# application, and have successfully got it to post (ajax post) file contents to an API Controller which can then be used to persist the file. While you don't mention if you are using MVC, the same should be possible using any sort of service.

Hope this helps.